# Javascript convert date string to date and time

Tags: javascript

I have a date string in the below format,

```
Wed Feb 21 2018 09:20:46 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

using Javascript want to convert the date string like this, i.e, date and time separated with 'T'.

```
2018-02-21T09:20:46.66
```

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) from `Date.prototype`.

Comment: Simply use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) to parse the string and output it in ISO 8601 format

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)

```
moment("Wed Feb 21 2018 09:20:46 GMT+0530 (IST)").format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS')
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a Date String to be converted to ISO Format. You can use the [`toISOString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString) method as follows:

```
var event = new Date('Wed Feb 21 2018 09:20:46 GMT+0530 (IST)');
console.log(event.toISOString());
```

Result is `"2018-02-21T03:50:46.000Z"`

You can use `.slice()` method to trim the last `Z` if you do not require it. You'd then have to use `event.toISOString().slice(0,-1)` to trim the last character in the returned ISO String.

Comment: You can use `.slice(0,-1)` at the end of the returned string to remove/chop the last `Z`. `event.toISOString().slice(0,-1)` is what you're looking for then.

Answer (score 0):

This Code will do it.

```
var date = new Date()
    date.toJSON().slice(0,10).replace(/-/g,'-') + "T" + 
    date.toJSON().split('T')[1].split('.')[0]
```